# convert system.Object[] to Datatable in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, datatable

I am trying to Deserialize `JSON` string and convert it to `DataTable`, using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

### VB Function:

```
Public Function DerializeDataTable(ByVal data As String) As DataTable
    Dim json As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim j As Object = json.DeserializeObject(data)
    Return j
End Function
```

### Exception:

*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.*

How to Deserialize the `Json` string to `datatable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) framework.
Then you can use the following code in your case

```
var table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
return table;
```

For vb.net

```
Dim dt as DataTable = Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(data)
```

So your complete function would be

```
Public Function DerializeDataTable(ByVal data As String) As DataTable 
    Dim j As DataTable = Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)(data)
    Return j
End Function
```